# How to fetch user info using twitter api v2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to fetch tweets from twitter into a dataframe, I have been able to fetch the tweets but there are some additional data that I would like to add like the username, retweet count. I have scoured the docs and tried everything to the best of my knowledge but I keep getting an error that it doesn't recognize the keyword user or username but I am also thinking its not possible to have tweets without a username

this is my code:

```
for _ in range(num_batches):
    response = client.search_recent_tweets(
        query='nurofen',
        max_results=100,
        until_id=until_id,
        tweet_fields=['author_id', 'created_at', 'text', 'lang', 'public_metrics'],
        user_fields=['name', 'username', 'location', 'id'],
        expansions=['author_id', 'entities.mentions.username'],

    )


    tweets_chunk = response.data

    if not tweets_chunk:
        break

    tweets.extend(tweets_chunk)

    until_id = tweets_chunk[-1].id


# Create a DataFrame from the extracted tweet data
tweet_data = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet_data.append({
        'Author ID': tweet.author_id,
        'Tweet ID': tweet.id,
        'Language': tweet.lang,
        'Created at': tweet.created_at,
        'Text': tweet.text,
        'Location': tweet.geo,
        'Username': tweet.users,
        'Retweet Count': tweet.data['retweet_count']
    })


nurofen_twts = pd.DataFrame(tweet_data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(nurofen_twts)
```

Comment: I have been able to get the retweet count but still having issues pulling the usernames, I keep getting a KeyError for the username

Comment: Hello! Can you please provide the full error code?